# How to update Lightroom catalogue with intentional file removal done in OS?

Tags: lightroom, file, delete

I intentionally deleted some files in a Lightroom catalogue storage folder in OS (Mac OS X).  Those files were once accidentally and incorrectly imported and all have file names ending with `-2.jpg`.  How to update the Lightroom catalogue file *properly* for this?  Any better way of doing this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use Lightroom's [Synchronize](http://livedocs.adobe.com/en_US/Lightroom/1.0/help.html?content=WS0E8634AC-5DB4-4d0c-9CF5-840A1BC95FA0.html) command.  You can execute this command at whatever level in your catalog is most appropriate, and you will have the option to remove all missing files which, if you have already intentionally deleted your image files, is what you want.

Answer (score 2):

> Any better way of doing this?

Yes: delete them from within Lightroom, which will remove them from the Lightroom catalog and gives you the option to delete from the filesystem.

To fix this, you can just go to Lightroom and find the file(s) you deleted and delete. You'll be warned that the file can't be found, and can just proceed.

Comment: If I programmatically deleted hundreds of files, do I have to manually process each one like this in LR?